# How can i show time in calendar in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to show time in a Magento calendar. For this I have followed the instructions as per [this url](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/48972/).

First I have modified `date.php` by changing this:

```
$this->getTime() ? 'true' : 'false',
```

to this:

```
$this->getTime() ? 'true' : 'true',
```

Then I have changed

```
$displayFormat = Varien_Date::convertZendToStrFtime($outputFormat, true, (bool)$this->getTime());
```

to

```
$displayFormat = Varien_Date::convertZendToStrFtime($outputFormat = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT));
```

Then i have updated the `en.xml` file, from:

```
<dateFormatLength type="short">
   <dateFormat>
      <pattern>M/d/yy</pattern>
   </dateFormat>
</dateFormatLength>
```

to:

```
<dateFormatLength type="short">
   <dateFormat>
      <pattern>M/d/yy h:mm a</pattern>
   </dateFormat>
</dateFormatLength>
```

Everything is working fine but I get a strange error; Now when I click on the calendar icon and change the value, the value in the input box is showing as `10/10/11 02:10 PM 02:10 PM`. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: how is this a error and what is the correct output you are looking for?

Comment: i am looking for this 10/10/11 02:10 PM.But right now i am getting 10/10/11 02:10 PM 02:10 PM.Time is showing twice

Comment: You should not change en.xml file or any core file, it is a Framework file which don't need to be edited. You have to use the framework method and classes to get a correct date time format. 
Why did you changed these files ? The forum post was already good: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/171494/ just replace Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM by Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example to get a field with date time calendar, tested on Magento 1.4 and above:

```
public function getHtmlDateStartOptions($product = null)
    {
    $configValue = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('subscription_date_start');
    $dateStrFormat = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

    $dateStartId = 'subscription_date_start';
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $element = $form->addField($dateStartId, 'date', array(
        'name'      => $dateStartId,
        'style'     => 'width:100px',
        'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'format'    => $dateStrFormat,
        'no_span'   => true,
        'time' => true,
    ));

    $element->setValue($configValue, $dateStrFormat);// date format must be defined here too, don't remove
    return $form->toHtml();
}
```